# Best way to create Sharepoint forms using Designer 2007 / WSS 3.0

Tags: sharepoint, forms

My company is running its own server with WSS 3.0, and I am using Sharepoint Designer 2007 to make changes. I am new to the world of sharepoint (but experienced with webservers and web programming), but basically what I am trying to accomplish is this:
We are trying to automate forms that all employees must fill out (for example, our Employment Application). Since all employees have access to our sharepoint intranet, we will put it on there.  It must do the following:

- Display a form where users can enter their data. Once submitted, the data is stored in a database (sharepoint uses Lists for this I believe).
- A user can go back to the form to edit things if need be (and their old data will be automatically loaded).
- User’s should only be able to access their own form and not see everyone else’s. Only admin’s should be able to see everyone’s stuff.

What is the best way to go about accomplishing this? Can I create a standard list and modify it to suit my needs? Do I need to code some ASP forms to make this work? Is there an inexpensive web part that can do this sorta stuff?

I don’t think using Infopath is an option for me since I have wss 3.0 I would need the end user to have infopath as well, and many won’t have it, so that rules that out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to adjust the Item Level Permissions setting of the list. (List Settings->Advanced Settings)

The form in SharePoint States:

**"Item-level Permissions
Specify which items users can read and edit. 
Note: Users with the Manage Lists permission can read and edit all items. Learn about managing permission settings."**

There are settings for Read access and Create and Edit access:

**Read access:**   Specify which items users are allowed to read
-Read all items 
-Read items that were created by the user

**Create and Edit access:**   Specify which items users are allowed to create and edit
-Create and edit all items
-Create items and edit items that were created by the user 
-None

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you simply need a custom list, possibly with custom forms (edited with SharePoint Designer) in case the default forms aren't adequate.